# AJAX Request successful but return empty data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a table in my MySQL and i display data on the page using FOR EACH loop. After that i did an ajax request to update every time my FOR EACH loop when in the database there is inserted a new raw.

The AJAX request is successful but returning empty data. I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I will appreciate any help. Maybe something wrong I am doing and WordPress is taking my code strange?

**File That I display data with FOR EACH Loop: ajax.php**

```html
// DB Connection (Wordpress)

global $wpdb;

$_IL_START = 0;
$_IL_LIMIT = 10;

if( isset($_GET['paged']) ){
    $_IL_ID = $_GET['paged'];
    $_IL_START = ($_IL_ID-1) * $_IL_LIMIT;
}

$_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL ORDER BY il_id DESC LIMIT $_IL_START, $_IL_LIMIT");

//FOR EACH Loop

echo '<ul id="list">';
foreach($_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL as $_IL_RESULT_DATA)
{
    echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_name;
    echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_email;
    $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_date;
}
echo '</ul>';
```

**File That I call that ajax.php with jquery: (display.php)**

```html
//require once the FOR EACH Loop

require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/ajax.php");

//and the JS Code

<script type="text/javascript" >
    fetch();
    function fetch(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '/ajax.php',
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery(data).hide().prependTo("#list").slideDown("slow");
                if(jQuery("#list li").length > 15){
                    jQuery('#list li:gt(14)').remove();
                }
                console.log(data);
                setTimeout("fetch()", 100);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**When I make console.log(data) is printing this only `< ul id="list" >< /ul >` and nothing else.**

**RESULT OF var_dump($_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL);**

```html
array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#427 (11) { ["il_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["il_name"]=> string(11) "Ion Luchian" ["il_email"]=> string(14) "adasdds@ffl.ll" ["il_from_mt4"]=> string(10) "2088408090" ["il_from_mt4_currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["il_to_mt4"]=> string(6) "534534" ["il_to_mt4_currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["il_comments"]=> string(0) "" ["il_status"]=> string(8) "approved" ["il_user_ip"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" ["il_date"]=> string(10) "2014-09-18" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#426 (11) { ["il_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["il_name"]=> string(11) "Ion Luchian" ["il_email"]=> string(13) "dasdas@.gg.gg" ["il_from_mt4"]=> string(10) "2088408090" ["il_from_mt4_currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["il_to_mt4"]=> string(7) "3112312" ["il_to_mt4_currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["il_comments"]=> string(51) "this my comment, appears only if the comment exists" ["il_status"]=> string(8) "approved" ["il_user_ip"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" ["il_date"]=> string(10) "2014-09-18" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#430 (11) { ["il_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["il_name"]=> string(11) "Ion Luchian" ["il_email"]=> string(14) "terterte@tt.ll" ["il_from_mt4"]=> string(10) "2088408090" ["il_from_mt4_currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["il_to_mt4"]=> string(6) "345345" ["il_to_mt4_currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["il_comments"]=> string(0) "" ["il_status"]=> string(8) "approved" ["il_user_ip"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" ["il_date"]=> string(10) "2014-09-18" } }
```

**This is my pagination:**

```html
$_IL_ROWS_COUNT = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL"));
$_IL_TOTAL = ceil( $_IL_ROWS_COUNT / $_IL_LIMIT );

if($_IL_LIMIT < $_IL_ROWS_COUNT){
echo '<span class="il_pagination_block_admin">';
if( $_IL_ID > 1 )
{
    echo "<a href='?page=il_internal_transfer&tab=il_internal_transfer&paged=".($_IL_ID-1)."' class='il_pagination_prev'><span class='il_pagination_prev_icon'></span></a>";
}

echo "<ul class='il_pagination'>";
for( $i = 1; $i <= $_IL_TOTAL; $i++ )
{
    if( $i == $_IL_ID ) { echo "<li class='il_pagination_current'>".$i."</li>"; }

    else { echo "<li><a href='?page=il_internal_transfer&tab=il_internal_transfer&paged=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; }
}
echo "</ul>";
if( $_IL_ID != $_IL_TOTAL )
{
    echo "<a href='?page=il_internal_transfer&tab=il_internal_transfer&paged=".( $_IL_ID + 1 )."' class='il_pagination_next'><span class='il_pagination_next_icon'></span></a>";
}

echo "</span>";
```

Comment: what is your requirement on ajax success ?

Comment: For example i have now 5 raw in my table that i display, somebody completes a form and in my table is inserted the 6th raw, so when the 6th raw is inserted i want automatically to update the for each loop and display it without any refresh of the page, and so anytime when in my table is inserted a new raw @TBI

Comment: I suppose your query fails. `$_IL_START, $_IL_LIMIT` - where are they set?

Comment: Have you checked if there is data in $_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL ??

Comment: @ionluchian Just do `var_dump($_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL);` at the end of your `ajax.php` and post the result.

Comment: I added the code that us aid that is failing, without ajax is working everything perfect, i can see my for each loop with all the data, but when i call the ajax is printing this in console <ul id="list"></ul> empty instead to update my for each loop. now i have really in the DB 3 raw that i can see them on the page, i insert the 4 raw and the for each loop is not updating it. @Marek

Comment: i inserted the result of var_dump, please check i updated the questio @IsmaelMiguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EXPLANATION**

```
on the server page (php) that receive the facebook notice, you have to put an extra check so

if( facebook_data_come ) { 

   // 1 - insert the new data inside your table

   // 2 - on a separate database table that you will call for example facebook_notification_check where you have an INT of 0 or 1 (default to 0), update it to 1 after the first step above.

   // 3 - on the ajax php page you will first check if  facebook_notification_check is equal to 1, if so you will continue with your code and reset the facebook_notification_check back to 0 otherwise you return an empty string...

}
```

---

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$html = 'unknown error';
$query = "SELECT * FROM $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL ORDER BY il_id DESC LIMIT $_IL_START, $_IL_LIMIT";
if($_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL = $wpdb->get_results($query)){
    if(count($_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL)){
        foreach($_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL as $_IL_RESULT_DATA)
        {
            $html = '<li>'. $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_name . $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_email . $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_date .'</li>';
        }
    } else {
        $html = '';
    }
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal server error");
    $html = mysql_error() . " | sql query : " . $query;
}
echo $html;
?>
```

---

```
<ul id="list"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    fetch();
    function fetch(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '/ajax.php',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data!=''){

                    jQuery(data).prependTo("#list");
                    jQuery('#list li:first-child').slideDown("slow");

                    setTimeout("fetch()", 100);
                }
            }, 
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i did again and now is something with jquery a conflict with load-scripts.php  Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 and the error is this "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " aSeptik

Comment: i fix it, i need to add all the variables i use in the ajax.php file, and now is updating the raw if is inserted in the database, but all my list of the loop is sliding down, i mean the entire <ul id=list""></ul> is sliding down every second as the interval is setup, now i want that will slide only the new <li></li> raw ... @aSeptik

Comment: it a mysql error, you have an error syntax in the used sql query i have updated the code to show the full query sended on the console log. check it and see what it the problem...

Comment: @ionluchian You need to change it so that `<ul>` tag is not in the answer (you would have nested list), then check if the data is not empty. This will require some refactoring.

Comment: i didn't press nothing, i put up now, the error i fixed already, can u help me to slide only the new raw inserted but not the entire list? because i have 6 raw and they are sliding down again and again, i want only to slide the new raw... @aSeptik

Comment: @Marek: off course it is always better to separate content from the logic... +1

Comment: could u help me with this sliding stuff? now all the list is sliding down, i need to slide only the new raw inserted? @Marek

Comment: @ionluchian: it is diffucult without knowing the entire code, anyway i guess you have to do something like this `fetch(next_slide_id)` then pass it via ajax like `ajax.php?next_slide_id=#` then use it in the sql query in the `LIMIT` clouse

Comment: the code from above is all my code, i just added now the code for pagination, now in the question is the full code that am using, please could u help me? @aSeptik

Comment: @ionluchian: `jQuery('#list li:first-child').slideDown("slow");` see the updated code...

Comment: now is duplicating the list with every request @aSeptik

Comment: i will click because it solved the first problem to update the list, just now i want to fix the second problem to slide down on the new raw  @aSeptik

Comment: @ionluchian : dear i have already updated my question to solve your second problem. if it doesn't work pls post the html code...

Comment: i updated my code as u did, and now every second is inserting one raw, and the raw is the same, i want to stop adding every second, just to add when a new raw is inserted, but now is more near what i am trying to do @aSeptik

Comment: is the same because the ajax request you made is always the same

Comment: yes i understood u, but if i have the same information i do not want to update it permanently, i want that the ajax request will update only when in the database is inserted a new raw, for example on Facebook u sit on your profile page, and when someone is sharing something is coming in your timeline, i am trying to do something like this, the information is sitting on the page as static and updating only when is something new.... do u understand what i mean? @aSeptik

Comment: @ionluchian: now i understand, in this case you have to use a flag that tell whenever fresh data come to your server. see the updated explanation

Comment: theoretically now i understood how is working, could u please help me with the code as well? maybe u can make a simple example and after i will implement in mine? @aSeptik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62396/discussion-between-ionluchian-and-aseptik).